# Recurrence Relation of function with a Loop

Tags: recurrence

I have been trying to find recurrence relation that represents the runtime of the following function. I know how to solve recurrence relations and functions without loop but I have 0 clue about the following function

```
function derp(n):
    if n == 0
      return 1
    sum = 0
    for i = 1 to 3
       sum = sum + derp(n-1)
    return sum
```

Comment: hint: try printing out the values of n, i, and sum at different parts of your recurssion and the inner for loop

Comment: I did that, this function basically calculates the power of 2. I can not find a way to tackle this problem

Comment: take a paper,pen and write down the value of n,sum manually on each function call, write it in a from of a tree like next fn call is a child of parent fn call and so on

Comment: Thanks @rakesh. I think the answer is 
T(0) = 1
T(n) = 3T(n-1)
and the run time is big-oh(3^n)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so answering myself,

We know that `$T(0)=0$.`

Otherwise, for $n>0$, we have:

```
$T(n)= 3T(n−1)$
```

This can be verified by using recursion tree